# How to Solve PDE using techniques of Separation Variables in this question [SOLVED]

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Hi guys my name is Maxwell. This is my first time I asking question in this forum. I hope someone can help me this problem out :

Question says :

$ U_{xx} + U_{yy} = U $. Solve this PDE product solution using separation of variables.

What I do is

$ X''(x)Y(y) + X(x)Y''(y)=X(x)Y(y) $

$ X''(x)Y(y)=X(x)[Y(y)-Y''(y)] $

$ \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)} $ = $ \frac{Y(y)-Y''(y)}{Y(y)}$= k, where k is a constant

Then I made into 3 cases where $ k>0 $, $k<0$ and $k=0$

I already got the answer for $k<0$ and $k=0$ which my teacher say correct but for $ k>0 $ my teacher say wrong because he said for $ k>0 $ case, we need to divide into another 3 sub cases.

My $ k>0 [Let k=p^2 ] $, I got my answer

$X(x)=Ae^{-px}+Be^{px}$

$Y(y)=Ce^{-\sqrt{1-p^2}y}$+$De^{\sqrt{1-p^2}y}$

For this part could somone please solve it for me.Please dont say tips and hints. I need some work shown from you so that I can understand better. Please guys I really need help from you. This my first time in this forum. If someone could solve it, i will be really appreciate it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260133/how-is-a-heat-partial-differential-equation-with-a-flux-term).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three cases are $1-p^2 > 0$, $=0$, $< 0$.

Comment: Why?? Could you show the final step please for the 3 sub cases. Please Im not good at PDE and I'm quite weak.I live in Malaysia and I dont have proper teacher to guide me. If you could show then I can analyse myself and try by myself later

Comment: My X(x) is correct just the Y(y) only it is wrong.So help me to proceed the Y(y) only please

Comment: This should be just like what you did for the $X$.  Exponentials in one case, sine and cosine in another, $1$ and $y$ in the third.

Comment: I really cant get it Sir. Really sorry Sir I'm totally blur about this. I still unable to get as what you said Sir.

Comment: Is it like this now; for $1-p^2>0$, $Y(y)=Ce^{-\sqrt{1-p^2}y}$+$De^{\sqrt{1-p^2}y}$ and for $1-p^2<0$, $Y(y)=Ccos{\sqrt{1-p^2}y}$+$Dsin{\sqrt{1-p^2}y}$. Could you recheck my answer  whether it is right or not Sir?? So that I can show to my teacher.

Comment: For $1-p^2 < 0$, you want $\sqrt{p^2-1}$, not $\sqrt{1-p^2}$.

Comment: Yeeah finally I got it correctly Sir. Thank you very much Sir for your kind help and effort.